# Enable/Disable Combobox according to Checkbox selection WIX

Tags: wix

How to Enable/Disable Combobox according to Checkbox selection. I want in the way like if checkbox is Checked then Combobox will be enabled and if checkbox is unchecked then combobox will be disabled. I didn't find any clue about putting conditions in Control of Type ComboBox.
Any suggestions?????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Condition to enable or disable the Combo box based on the Check box property.

```
<Control Id="ComboBox_Test" Type="ComboBox" X="147" Y="60" Width="163" Height="16" Property="TEST">
     <Condition Action="enable">TestCheckBox=1</Condition>
     <Condition Action="disable">TestCheckBox &lt;&gt; 1</Condition>
</Control>

<Control Type="CheckBox" Id="CheckBox_Test" Width="105" Height="17" X="158" Y="172" Text="Test" CheckBoxValue="1" Property="TestCheckBox" />
```

**EDIT:**

For your requirement, it would be like this.

```
  <Control Id="AppPoolCombo" Type="ComboBox" Property="APPPOOLVALUE" Sorted="yes" ComboList="yes" X="165" Y="124" Width="149" Height="16">
                <ComboBox Property="APPPOOLVALUE">
                    <ListItem Text="Default Application Pool" Value="Default Application Pool" />
                    <ListItem Text="Integrated" Value="Integrated" />
                    <ListItem Text="Classic" Value="Classic" />
                </ComboBox>
              <Condition Action="enable">TestCheckBox=1</Condition>
              <Condition Action="disable">TestCheckBox &lt;&gt; 1</Condition>
            </Control>
```

Comment: <Control Id="AppPoolCombo" Type="ComboBox" Property="APPPOOLVALUE"   Sorted="yes" ComboList="yes" X="45" Y="73" Width="250" Height="16" >
          <ComboBox Property="APPPOOLVALUE" >
            <ListItem Text="Default Application Pool" Value="Default Application Pool"/>
            <ListItem Text="Integrated" Value="Integrated"/>
            <ListItem Text="Classic" Value="Classic"/>
          </ComboBox>
        </Control>                                                                                                                              I need to disable when check box is checked.